# Which value to use as standardcontroller on VisualForce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

The idea is that I'm going to pass in the User ID in the URL of the page and then I'm going to query all of the items of a custom objects (SM_cast__c) that belong to that user on the VF page.

So I start with this at the top of the VF page:

```
<apex:page StandardController="User" Extensions="MonthlyForecastPageController">
```

With this code getting the ID in the controller:

```
SM = (User)controller.getRecord();
```

And I get this error when compiling the VF page:

```
Compilation error: common.apex.runtime.bytecode.BytecodeApexObjectType
cannot be cast to common.apex.runtime.impl.ApexType
```

So I decide to switch the VF page around and use the custom object.

```
<apex:page StandardController="SM_cast__c" Extensions="MonthlyForecastPageController">
```

With this in the controller code:

```
SM_ID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
```

and I get this error in the browser when I run the page:

```
Id value 005500000011TPK is not valid for the SM_cast__c standard controller
```

I don't do Salesforce programming on a daily basis, so I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

thanks!

lee

Comment: how are you calling this vf page? means from a button or from where?

Comment: Currently I'm not. I'm just pasting the URL into the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value which you are getting from the page as an ID(005500000011TPK) is of a user. And as you have defined your standard controller as "SM_cast__c". You can only pass a record of that custom object as the Id.

If your ask is to have a standard controller for the custom object and still pass the user Id i the url, you need to change the parameter variable on the URL to UserId or some other value instead of "Id".

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Set VF page to use SM_cast__c as standardcontroller, pass in param as UserId, then changed code to getParameters().get('UserId') got it to work. Thanks!